# Absolutely position elements inside a fixed position container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to absolutely position elements inside a fixed position container? For example:

```
<div style="position:fixed; left:0; top:0">
    <div style="position:fixed; left:0; top:0;"></div>
    <div style="position:fixed; left:200px; top:120px;"></div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to move, using jQuery, the container div to the left and right (and it's children along with it), but this obviously doesn't work (moving the container's left property does not affect the children).

I tried something like this:

```
<div style="position:fixed; left:0; top:0">
    <div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:100%;">
        <div style="position:fixed; left:0; top:0;"></div>
        <div style="position:fixed; left:200px; top:120px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...but it doesn't work. I know I could ultimately just drop the container and animate each of the fixed position children at the same time, but I'd really prefer not to. I'll probably end up adding more children later, and that would mean managing the animations/movements of each one (now that I think of it, I could just add a class to each child, and have jQuery animate the left property of all occurances of that class, but I'd still prefer to resolve my initial problem if possible).

[Hacks are welcome!](http://jsfiddle.net/hLDw6/)

Comment: I'm unsure as what exactly you are trying to achieve, you could draw an image to help me understand? Also i think you mean the sub elements to be position: absolute; rather than fixed?

Comment: That link is a fiddle

Comment: Your question asks about putting absolute divs inside of a fixed div, yet your code shows fixed divs inside of a fixed div...

Comment: Yeah, setting the children to absolute position fixed it. I wanted the container and everything in it to be fixed during page scroll, but I had assumed that meant the children should have position fixed as well as the container. I stupidly never even tried position absolute on the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The children should be position absolute (because they are positioned absolutely within the fixed container).

See this demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/74dE7/2/

```
#fixed-box {
    position: fixed;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

#absolute-box {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    background: blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

<div id="fixed-box">
    <div id="absolute-box">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use relative for the children, not fixed.

```
<div style="position:fixed; left:0; top:0">
    <div style="position:relative; left:0; top:0;"></div>
    <div style="position:relative; left:200px; top:120px;"></div>
</div>
```